# PHP script success/fail message on same page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to return a success/failure message from a PHP script on the same page however I don't seem to be getting any message returned at all at the moment. Here is my code:

PHP:

```
    <?php
if ( isset( $_POST['CollectorIP'] ) && isset($_POST['CollectorPort']) && isset($_POST['NetflowVersion']) && isset($_POST['Flowrate']) && isset($_POST['TemplateFrequency']) && isset($_POST['SourceIPAddress']) && isset($_POST['DestinationIPAddress']) ) {
    // ok let's try to create the file
    $path = '/usr/local/flowsim/data/' . trim($_POST['CollectorIP']) . ':' . trim($_POST['CollectorPort']) . ':' . trim($_POST['NetflowVersion']) . '.conf';
    $contents = "";
    if ( $fh = fopen($path,"a+") ) {
        if ( trim( $_POST['CollectorIP'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= 'collector-ip=' . $_POST['CollectorIP'];
        }
        if ( trim( $_POST['CollectorPort'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'collector-port=' . $_POST['CollectorPort'];
        }
        if ( trim( $_POST['NetflowVersion'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'engine=' . $_POST['NetflowVersion'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['Flowrate'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'flow-rate=' . $_POST['Flowrate'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['TemplateFrequency'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'template-freq=' . $_POST['TemplateFrequency'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['SourceIPAddress'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'src-ip=' . $_POST['SourceIPAddress'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['DestinationIPAddress'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'dst-ip=' . $_POST['DestinationIPAddress'];
        }
        if ( fwrite( $fh, $contents ) ) {
            echo "Netflow traffic is now being sent to the collector at ". ( $_POST['CollectorIP'] ). " on port ". ( $_POST['CollectorPort'] ). ".";
        } else {
            "The simulator was unable to start the traffic flow, please try again.";
        }
        fclose($fh); // Close the file
    }
}
?>
```

I have tried changing the HTML page to .php and including the PHP script inside the page and having the form submit to itself, like the below however this still returns no message. The PHP script is running successfully because it creates the `.conf` file when the form is submitted:

```
        <div class="u-form u-form-1">
          <form id="Netflow" action="" class="u-clearfix u-form-spacing-25 u-form-vertical u-inner-form" name="Netflow" method="POST" style="padding: 10px;">
            <div class="u-form-group u-form-name u-form-partition-factor-2 u-label-top">
              <label for="CollectorIP" class="u-custom-font u-heading-font u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-1">Collector IP Address</label>
              <input id="CollectorIP" type="text" placeholder="Collector IP Address"  name="CollectorIP" minlength="7" maxlength="15" pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$" input required class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-50 u-white u-input-1" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="u-form-email u-form-group u-form-partition-factor-2 u-label-top">
              <label for="CollectorPort" class="u-custom-font u-heading-font u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-2">Collector Port</label>
              <input id="CollectorPort" type="number" placeholder="Collector Port" name="CollectorPort" class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-50 u-white u-input-2" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="u-form-group u-form-select u-label-top u-form-group-3">
              <label for="NetflowVersion" class="u-custom-font u-heading-font u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-3">Netflow Version</label>
              <div class="u-form-select-wrapper">
                <select id="NetflowVersion" name="NetflowVersion" class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-50 u-white u-input-3" required="required">
                  <option value="builtin-v10">Netflow Version 10 (IPFIX)</option>
                  <option value="builtin-v9">Netflow Version 9</option>
                  <option value="builtin-v7">Netflow Version 7</option>
                  <option value="builtin-v5">Netflow Version 5</option>
                </select>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="12" version="1" class="u-caret"><path fill="currentColor" d="M4 8L0 4h8z"></path></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-form-group u-form-partition-factor-2 u-form-select u-label-top u-form-group-4">
              <label for="Flowrate" class="u-custom-font u-heading-font u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-4">Flow Rate (per second)</label>
              <div class="u-form-select-wrapper">
                <select id="Flowrate" name="Flowrate" class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-50 u-white u-input-4">
                  <option value="1">100 (Default)</option>
                  <option value="10">1,000</option>
                  <option value="100">10,000</option>
                  <option value="1000">100,000</option>
                </select>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="12" version="1" class="u-caret"><path fill="currentColor" d="M4 8L0 4h8z"></path></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-form-group u-form-partition-factor-2 u-label-top u-form-group-5">
              <label for="TemplateFrequency" class="u-custom-font u-heading-font u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-5">Template Frequency (seconds)</label>
              <input id="TemplateFrequency" type="number" placeholder="Template Frequency"  name="TemplateFrequency" class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-50 u-white u-input-5">
            </div>
            <div id='Source-IP-Address' class="u-form-group u-form-partition-factor-2 u-label-top u-form-group-6">
              <label for="SourceIPAddress" class="u-custom-font u-heading-font u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-6">Source IP Address</label>
              <input id="SourceIPAddress" type="text" placeholder="Source IP Address" name="SourceIPAddress" minlength="7" maxlength="15" pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$" class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-50 u-white u-input-1">
            </div>
            <div id='Destination-IP-Address' class="u-form-group u-form-partition-factor-2 u-label-top u-form-group-7">
              <label for="DestinationIPAddress" class="u-custom-font u-heading-font u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-7">Destination IP Address</label>
              <input id="DestinationIPAddress" type="text" placeholder="Destination IP Address"  name="DestinationIPAddress"  minlength="7" maxlength="15" pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$" class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-50 u-white u-input-1">
            </div>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Source-IP-Address, #Destination-IP-Address').hide();
        $('.u-btn-2').click(function() {
            if ($('#Source-IP-Address, #Destination-IP-Address').is(':hidden')) {
                 $('#Source-IP-Address, #Destination-IP-Address').slideDown();
            } else {
                 $('#Source-IP-Address, #Destination-IP-Address').slideUp();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
            <div class="u-align-left u-form-group u-form-submit u-label-top">
              <input type="submit" value="submit" class="u-form-control-hidden">
              <a href="#" class="u-btn u-btn-round u-btn-submit u-button-style u-custom-color-2 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-radius-50 u-btn-1">Submit</a>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="u-border-none u-btn u-btn-round u-button-style u-custom-color-2 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-hover-feature u-radius-50 u-text-body-alt-color u-btn-2">+</a>

<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['CollectorIP'] ) && isset($_POST['CollectorPort']) && isset($_POST['NetflowVersion']) && isset($_POST['Flowrate']) && isset($_POST['TemplateFrequency']) && isset($_POST['SourceIPAddress']) && isset($_POST['DestinationIPAddress']) ) {
    // ok let's try to create the file
    $path = '/usr/local/flowsim/data/' . trim($_POST['CollectorIP']) . ':' . trim($_POST['CollectorPort']) . ':' . trim($_POST['NetflowVersion']) . '.conf';
    $contents = "";
    if ( $fh = fopen($path,"a+") ) {
        if ( trim( $_POST['CollectorIP'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= 'collector-ip=' . $_POST['CollectorIP'];
        }
        if ( trim( $_POST['CollectorPort'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'collector-port=' . $_POST['CollectorPort'];
        }
        if ( trim( $_POST['NetflowVersion'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'engine=' . $_POST['NetflowVersion'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['Flowrate'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'flow-rate=' . $_POST['Flowrate'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['TemplateFrequency'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'template-freq=' . $_POST['TemplateFrequency'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['SourceIPAddress'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'src-ip=' . $_POST['SourceIPAddress'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['DestinationIPAddress'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'dst-ip=' . $_POST['DestinationIPAddress'];
        }
        if ( fwrite( $fh, $contents ) ) {
            // yay
        } else {
            // do some sort of error handling because the file couldn't be written to
        }
        fclose($fh); // Close the file
    } else {
            if ( fclose($fh) ){

             echo "Netflow traffic is now being sent to the collector at ". ( $_POST['CollectorIP'] ). " on port ". ( $_POST['CollectorPort'] ). ".";
    }
 else {
  echo "The simulator was unable to start the traffic flow, please try again.";
 }
    }
}
?>
      </div>
```

Are my `echo` success/fail messages correct in the PHP script? Why am I not seeing these when the form is submitted? Thanks!

**Update**

PHP:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['CollectorIP'] ) && isset($_POST['CollectorPort']) && isset($_POST['NetflowVersion']) && isset($_POST['Flowrate']) && isset($_POST['TemplateFrequency']) && isset($_POST['SourceIPAddress']) && isset($_POST['DestinationIPAddress']) ) {
    // ok let's try to create the file
    $path = '/usr/local/flowsim/data/' . trim($_POST['CollectorIP']) . ':' . trim($_POST['CollectorPort']) . ':' . trim($_POST['NetflowVersion']) . '.conf';
    $contents = "";
    if ( $fh = fopen($path,"a+") ) {
        if ( trim( $_POST['CollectorIP'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= 'collector-ip=' . $_POST['CollectorIP'];
        }
        if ( trim( $_POST['CollectorPort'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'collector-port=' . $_POST['CollectorPort'];
        }
        if ( trim( $_POST['NetflowVersion'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'engine=' . $_POST['NetflowVersion'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['Flowrate'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'flow-rate=' . $_POST['Flowrate'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['TemplateFrequency'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'template-freq=' . $_POST['TemplateFrequency'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['SourceIPAddress'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'src-ip=' . $_POST['SourceIPAddress'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['DestinationIPAddress'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'dst-ip=' . $_POST['DestinationIPAddress'];
        }
        if ( fwrite( $fh, $contents ) ) {
            echo "Netflow traffic is now being sent to the collector at ". ( $_POST['CollectorIP'] ). " on port ". ( $_POST['CollectorPort'] ). ".";
        } else {
            echo "The simulator was unable to start the traffic flow, please try again.";
        }
        fclose($fh); // Close the file
    }
}
?>
```

Test Script:

```
<script>
// Attach a submit handler to the form
$( "#Netflow" ).submit(function( event ) {
 
  // Stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();
 
  // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var formData = {
      CollectorIP: $("#CollectorIP").val(),
      CollectorPort: $("#CollectorPort").val(),
      NetflowVersion: $("#NetflowVersion").val(),
      Flowrate: $("#Flowrate").val(),
      TemplateFrequency: $("#TemplateFrequency").val(),
      SourceIPAddress: $("#SourceIPAddress").val(),
      DestinationIPAddress: $("#DestinationIPAddress").val(),
    };
 
  // Send the data using post
  var posting = $.post( "filewrite.php", formData );
 
  // Put the results in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );
    $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
  });
});
</script>
```

[image: Test-New-Flow.html]

[image: filewrite.php]

Comment: There is a **lot** of code to read through here, and very little description of where the problem is. Could you try to make a [mre] that just shows the part you're having problems with.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "message" in an HTML page, there's only HTML that shows a message. But you're doing `echo` without wrapping your message in some kind of HTML. Look at View Source in your browser. Do the messages appear there? Also, look at your browser devtools

Comment: @IMSoP of course sorry about that. I have removed some of the code. My main issue is I am trying to return the echo messages I have in my PHP script once the form is submitted on the same page. At the moment no echo messages are returned.

Comment: The posted PHP code never echo any success case. You only echo if you failed to open the file handler (which you then also try to close in that `else`-branch, even though it will only enter that if it _didn't_ manage to open it in the first place)

Comment: @M.Eriksson I am using the PHP script to create new files based on the HTML form inputs. How can I modify the echo messages in the script to return success if the file is written to successfully and failure if it is not? Sorry I am still learning PHP

Comment: It looks like the piece of code that actually echos data is outside the logic block that opens,writes to and then closes the file. Good code indentation and presentation help enormously.

Comment: Well if you want it to echo something when the file is successfully written to then simply put an `echo` inside `if ( fwrite( $fh, $contents ) ) {`...since that's the place where you're testing for a successful write.

Comment: The `if ( fclose($fh) ){` makes no sense as it is within the piece that handles not opening the file for writing.

Comment: @ADyson please check out my edit, is this correct for echo'ing once the file was written to? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? But no, that'll produce a syntax error. the command needs to be within the `{` and `}` of the `if` block. Please a) double-check your work more carefully, b) enable error reporting if you haven't already, and c) ensure you understand the very basics of PHP syntax :-)

Comment: @Darren `!=` doesn't assign anything, to my knowledge. https://onlinephp.io/c/73b83 . Also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Thanks @ADyson I made the edit. The script is still running and writing to the file but returns no success/failure message. I changed the HTML form to run the script as its `action="filewrite.php"` to see if on submit it would redirect with the output of the `echo` message but no luck. 

I don't see why it is not returning the echo, any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Davearoo32 you might need to look at what the return values are from [`fwrite()`](https://www.php.net/fwrite) as it seems to return bytes written or false potentially.

Comment: You'll need to narrow it down then. e.g. Add some `else`s to every `if` and some `var_dump` statements in plenty of places so you can see exactly what path the code is taking and what the values of the important variables are (e.g. the ones which control the `if`s). Or use a debugger such as XDebug. https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/ has a simple guide to debugging with PHP if it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys, I believe I found the reason for the issue here. My echo's are returning but because the form is running a background request via JavaScript the messages are not being returned on the HTML page. 

Looks like I will need an AJAX post request to send the data and return the success/fail on the page without refreshing.

Comment: Well "background request via JavaScript" is already an AJAX request. So probably you just need to collect the response from that (assuming you mean that the request is run when the form is submitted) and use JS to display it. Show the relevant JS code if you need help with it.

Comment: @ADyson sure thanks, I have edited my question with the revised PHP script and the JS I am trying to write to pass the request to and from the HTML form. 

I check the response in my browser dev tools and I can see the PHP return the echo response message when the file was successfully written to, it just isn't returned on the page. So I just need a little help with the JS to capture the returned message and display it on the HTML page.

Comment: Thanks. `echo` isn't a JavaScript command. Also I don't see how this is successfully sending this to the server because I don't think you're using the $.post command correctly. I'd expect it to look more like this: `$.post('filewrite.php', formData, function(response) {
        alert(response); 
      })` - see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ . If you want to do something more sophisticated with the response than just alerting it in a popup, learn some JS/jQuery DOM commands, so you can set the HTML of an existing element, or insert a new element containing your content.

Comment: @ADyson at the moment I just have the form submitting to itself and have the whole page as PHP. In the dev tools I can see the PHP response as expected so the return messages look to be working okay. 

I was trying to follow the guide here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery for the AJAX part. Ideally I am wanting the message to be returned as a `<div>` on the HTML page rather than a browser alert/pop-up which this guide seems to show is possible. 

Do I need to save the success & fail messages as variables to pass these back to the JS?

Comment: `$("#someDivID").text(response);` should do the trick, for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249227/discussion-between-davearoo-32-and-adyson).